# fSpy importing camera into an existing scene

Tags: fspy

It seems relatively easy to use fSpy’s camera to build a scene from a reference.

However, i am struggling to use it to add a camera to an existing scene.

For example, when the camera is imported, what are the criteria for where it is placed? In reference to what in the existing scene?

For context, a client sent me a photo of their largish product, which they wanted to be placed into a laboratory scene. (I cannot share screenshots bc this is an in progress, proprietary project)

I used fSpy to figure out their camera position, height, lens etc on the product.

On importing that camera into my scene, I found myself struggling to put the camera where it needed to be in the room, without messing up the height and angle along the way.

Any ideas or helpful hints?

Answer (score 3):

"It seems relatively easy" indeed, but it helps if you take some time to explore the real power of f-spy.

The first piece of information you need is the **lens focal length** and **camera sensor size** used to make the original image. Without it is going to be hard to get accurate placement.

Unfortunately f-spy wrongly labels "focal length" settings for *Sensor Size*

You might need to refer to a Lens to Field of View calculator (there are many on the internet) to get the field of view for your lens in degrees (not in mm)

The second part of the puzzle is working with real measurements, fSpy will not guess them for you.

[image]

Then, manually move the 3 axis tool in f-spy to set the origin and alignment of the scene: the white dot will determine the placement for the "floor" on the blender scene.

Without any real measurements there all you will get from spy is the  field of view on an arbitrary scene with arbitrary scale and relative distances, making it harder for you to approximate existing elements in blender.