# Use FSpy data to automatically create a plane from perspective angles and sample size

Tags: fspy

Is there an automated way to create a plane from a set of perspective angles and a sample size (for example, the length of one brick)?

This is data coming from FSpy (https://fspy.io), and I do not want to guess at making a reference plane (or object).

This is added functionality which I believe is redundant for what is already coming in from FSpy. The dimensions and axis should define not only camera, but an object, much like a cube is placed in the center of a new Blender scene.

I am interested in programming solutions, and not necessarily interactive solutions.

Comment: If you set up fspy correctly, with the correct lens, sensor size and set the scale (most important) then you don't need to guess much. create the objects in blender and the scale should be correct if you set it at the correct distance from the camera.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187800/fspy-importing-camera-into-an-existing-scene/187808#187808

Comment: I can set the size, and create a plane manually. But I need a plane placed automatically. I have edited the question to show the reasons.